# Design to support request processing as per object types

Tags: java, oop, asynchronous, gson

As per an use-case, this is what we do:

1. Expose multiple `Async` service APIs with different arguments (ex. InputObject1, InputObject2 etc.).
2. Client calls these APIs with proper input type and we send response back to client and push input object in a queue (ex. SQS) in JSON form (using Gson).
3. Another poller, keeps on polling the queue and receives messages from the queue. On receiving the message, poller has to do the task as per inputObject type.

There are two places my code could look dirty:

```
a. How to check the type of object on receiving from the queue? This would be in JSON format and I will have to convert JSON back to object. It will belong to one of the multiple potential objects.

b. Once type is known, how to call class responsible to handle that object?
```

What could be the optimal design for this use-case?

```
For a), one option is to create a `RequestWrapper` containing all the objects and populating the one this message belongs to.
```

Couple of ways I can think for b) are as following:

```
1. Add another parameter to the object and pass it to queue. Use this parameter to identify API called.
2. Use `instanceof` to get exact requestObject using multiple if-else and do the needful.
```

Though, these don't seem very neat to me. Any better suggestions?

```
==Edit==
```

@A4L

1. No, they don't share any common interface (at least, as of now).
2. Yes, we can modify these objects in the start (if that's what you mean by "implementation"). Since, we can change this, I can make them share a common interface, if required.

Thanks,

Comment: nice, then you might consider my suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to introduce at least one new interfaces `QueueTaskAble` which will be implement by your input objects and a second - optional, could  simply be `java.lang.Runnable` - which then executes the Task with some sort of `run` or `execute` method.

Here is how it could look like:

```
interface QueueTaskAble {
    Runnable getQueueTask();
}

class InputObjectFooQueueTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub            
    }
}

class InputObjectFooImpl implements QueueTaskAble {
    @Override
    public Runnable getQueueTask() {
        return new InputObjectFooQueueTask();
    }
}

void processQueueInputObject(QueueTaskAble queueObject) {
    queueObject.getQueueTask().run();
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Unfortunately it is not possible to natively deserialize as interface using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). To be able to do so you need to implement a type adapter which you can pass to [GsonBuilder#registerTypeAdapter](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter%28java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.Object%29) so that your object are properly serialized and deserialized.

Here is how you could go about it:

The type adapter

```
public class GenericGsonTypeAdapter<T> implements JsonSerializer<T>, 
        JsonDeserializer<T> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(T src, Type typeOfSrc, 
                    JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
        jo.addProperty("className", src.getClass().getName());
        jo.add("jsonData", context.serialize(src));
        return jo;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        T obj = null;
        if(json instanceof JsonObject) {
            JsonObject jo = (JsonObject) json;
            JsonElement jeJson = jo.get("jsonData");
            if(jeJson != null) {
                JsonElement jeClassName = jo.get("className");
                try {
                    obj = context.deserialize(json,
                                Class.forName(jeClassName.getAsString()));
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new JsonParseException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }   
}
```

A custom [Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) builder (unfortunately [GsonBuilder](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) is final and thus cannot be extended, hence as static final member)

```
public class InputObjectGsonBuilder {
    private final static GsonBuilder gb;
    static {
        gb = new GsonBuilder();
        gb.registerTypeAdapter(QueueTaskAble.class,
                    new GenericGsonTypeAdapter<QueueTaskAble>());
    }

    public Gson create() {
        return gb.create();
    }
}
```

A sample queue

```
public class InputObjectGsonQueue {

    private Queue<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public boolean pushInputObject(String json) {
        return queue.offer(json);
    }

    public void processQueue() {
        InputObjectGsonBuilder gb = new InputObjectGsonBuilder();
        String json;
        while(null != (json = queue.poll())) {
            QueueTaskAble queueTaskAble = gb.create().fromJson(json,
                               QueueTaskAble.class);
            processQueueInputObject(queueTaskAble);
        }
    }

    private void processQueueInputObject(QueueTaskAble queueObject) {
        queueObject.getQueueTask().run();
        // or for asynchronous processing
        // new Thread(queueObject.getQueueTask()).start();
    }
}
```

Some input objects and tasks implementations

```
public class InputObjectFooImpl implements QueueTaskAble {
    @Override
    public Runnable getQueueTask() {
        return new InputObjectFooTaksImpl();
    }
}

public class InputObjectBarImpl implements QueueTaskAble {
    @Override
    public Runnable getQueueTask() {
        return new InputObjectBarTaksImpl();
    }
}

public class InputObjectFooTaksImpl implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Foo!");
    }
}

public class InputObjectBarTaksImpl implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Bar!");
    }
}
```

And finally a sample application

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        InputObjectGsonBuilder gb = new InputObjectGsonBuilder();

        InputObjectGsonQueue gq = new InputObjectGsonQueue();
        gq.pushInputObject(gb.create().toJson(new InputObjectFooImpl(), 
                    QueueTaskAble.class));
        gq.pushInputObject(gb.create().toJson(new InputObjectBarImpl(), 
                    QueueTaskAble.class));

        gq.processQueue();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Foo!
Bar!
```

Comment: Answered your question in "Edit" section.

Comment: If I am not wrong, getQueueTask() in your case takes a task from queue and calls corresponding runnable class. I am more interested into that part. How do we get the specific class to call to? 

Also, converting Json received from queue to object type (modified the question with details).